# objective C compare property with nil

Tags: objective-c, null

In my code I have a property inside my custom ViewController:

```
@interface MyViewController()
@property (nullable) id<MyProxy> currentProxy;
@end
```

MyViewController is created inside a parent view controller viewDidLoad. On the event of a button clicked, [MyViewControllerInstance doThing] is called. In which there is the below check. Before it's assigned, underlying instance variable _currentProxy = id(0x0) in debug windows, which is correct, however, the below statement evaluates to true

```
if (self.currentProxy != nil)
```

It only works correctly when I replace self.currentProxy with _currentProxy. My question is, what the default getter do in this case?

Comment: Show all the code you use to define the variable

Comment: That's all there is to it. I just declare it as @property

Comment: At which point do you check  for `if (self.currentProxy != nil)`?

Comment: Are you using self.currentProxy in an initializer method ?

Comment: I updated my question to give more context.

Comment: _currentProxy gets the actual value of currentProxy, while self.currentProxy calls currentProxy getter, if you have any.

Comment: There's something else going on that you aren't showing.  A synthesized getter simply returns the synthesized instance variable.